# module.exports is undefined in Vue application

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I'm new to Vue. I have a Vue file and in the  section I use an import command.

```
<script>
import Module from '../module.js'
```

module.js uses `module.exports.example1 = function() { return true }`

However, this fails with the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'example1' of undefined`

When I do `console.log(module)` it also shows exports as undefined.

Why is exports undefined? Is there a better place I should place this module?

Comment: What environment/bundler are you using? Is `module.js` being handled as a CommonJS or ESM module? If it's the latter, then `module.exports` isn't a thing, which would explain this error.

Comment: Thanks! This is where I get confused. How do I know if it's CommonJS or ESM?

Comment: [ESM](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) is `import _ from 'module'` while [CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) is `require('module')`. [This article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/03/es-modules-a-cartoon-deep-dive/) explains it all in detail.